# Capturing 'enter' key on input not working

Tags: javascript, listener, enter, keyup

I'm going crazy trying to figure out why this isn't working... I have a text field and I want to capture when someone pushes enter so that the 'next' button can be focused.

This is more or less the input with id of 'guess'.

```
<input type='text' size='30' id='guess' autocomplete='off' value='' onMouseOver='javascript:this.focus();'>
```

I've added this event listener, but it's not activating...

```
document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener('keydown', focusnextbutton(event));

function focusnextbutton(e){
    alert('you pushed a button');
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        // alert('Button was enter');
        // document.getElementById('next_btn').focus();
    }
}
```

The 'you pushed a button' alert isn't even coming up and I cannot work out why. Help? I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it's not working either but if you change the line to:

```
document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener('keydown', focusnextbutton,false);
```

it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the brackets after the focusnextbutton function.

`document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener('keydown', focusnextbutton);`

This is because the second argument of addEventListener is a function to call. When the code is run for the first time, addEventListener runs the second argument immediately and expects a function to be returned for the argument. For example, you could also do:

`document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener('keydown', function(){
    focusnextbutton(event);
});`

The anonymous function as the second argument is a function definition and therefore is not run when the code is first evaluated, but IS run on keydown.

You will notice that the alert 'you pushed a button' is run immediately when the page loads. This is because the function is called while the event listener is being added and was key for debugging this error.

Comment: Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e44asjfq/). I believe it behaves as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
    focusnextbutton(event);
});
```

Pass the event argument to the callback function too. That's what's missing from the previous answers.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WoleO/3anxwe69/)